# Awaiting events to be fired from task list

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I am starting several tasks using `Task.Run()`. Within each of these tasks, I define an event handler for `InstallCompleted`. Then, I `await` for these tasks to finish. The tricky bit is that the `installModule.Install()` method seen below returns immediately because internally it calls a `OneWay` WCF service call.

So, how do I `await` until all instances of `installModule` in each task above have fired their respective `InstallCompleted` events? If there is a better way to accomplish this, I'm all ears.

```
var installTasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var targetMachine in vm.TargetMachines)
{
    var installTask = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        foreach (var module in Modules)
        {
            var installModule = module as IInstallModule;  // copy closure variable
            if (installModule == null)
                continue;

            installModule.InstallCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                //TODO set some flag indicating this install is complete
            };

            var ip = new Progress<InstallProgress>();
            installModule.Install(targetMachine.MachineName, ip);
        }
    });

    installTasks.Add(installTask);
}

await Task.WhenAll(installTasks);  // unblocks immediately because installModule.Install() above returns immediately
```

Answer (score 9):

Whenever you're [interoperating `async` with another kind of asynchronous API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can use `TaskCompletionSource<T>` as an asynchronous one-time signal. Personally, I like to do this as an extension method:

```
public static Task<InstallCompletedResult> InstallAsync(
    this IInstallModule module, string machineName,
    IProgress<InstallProgress> progress = null)
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<InstallCompletedResult>();
  InstallCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
  handler = (s, e) =>
  {
    module.InstallCompleted -= handler;
    if (e.Exception != null)
      tcs.TrySetException(e.Exception);
    else
      tcs.TrySetResult(e.Result);
  };
  module.InstallCompleted += handler;
  module.Install(machineName, progress);
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

Once you have the interop piece in, consuming it is quite straightforward:

```
var installTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
  var tasks = new List<Task>();
  foreach (var module in Modules)
  {
    var installModule = module as IInstallModule;  // copy closure variable
    if (installModule == null)
      continue;

    var ip = new Progress<InstallProgress>();
    tasks.Add(installModule.InstallAsync(targetMachine.MachineName, ip));
  }
});
```

Or, more simply:

```
var installTask = Task.Run(async () =>
{
  var tasks = Modules.OfType<IInstallModule>()
      .Select(module => module.InstallAsync(targetMachine.MachineName,
          new Progress<InstallProgress>()));
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
});
```

Comment: What's the advantage of the extension method? I wrote the whole solution, so I can rearchitect it wherever necessary. I have `IInstallModule` and `ModuleBase : IInstallModule` which I can modify.

Comment: You certainly could write a `ModuleBase.InstallAsync` - nothing wrong with that! Extension methods are usually used when you don't control the API (or if you don't have a common base class and don't want to add it to every implementation now).

Comment: Fortunately for me, this is a new project and I have complete autonomy! I will give this a try in the morning and I'll let you know how it works for me. Thanks again!

Comment: In your extension method above, you're missing a return type. What should it be?

Comment: Fixed. The interop pattern always returns the `Task` property of the `TaskCompletionSource<T>` instance.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much. Will revert shortly with progress.

Comment: It looks like it's invoking the agent asynchronously, but I'm not receiving my progress events. Would you mind taking a look? https://gist.github.com/mrichman/40ced4a50589c9f0f119

Comment: @MarkRichman: I tried, but there's too much code there for me to keep it all in my head. Could you post a minimal repro, perhaps as a followup question?